# Cannot move a site to the local server

Tags: migrations

I am a complete newbie to Drupal, although I have many years of PHP development and even more years as a system administrator. My task is to move a few Drupal sites from CentOS 5.x/Drupal 6.x to Centos 6.x and Drupal 7.x

My plan is to move all sites to Centos 6.x and then upgrade to 7.x (if possible).

I downloaded the first drupal site using rsync and then I exported the relevant database with mysqldump.

I imported the database and created the appropriate mysql user with the same permissions as in the production server.

Important: In my local server I use the domain **"testsite.local"**
The production domain is "testsite.com".

Now, the problem: When I enter testsite.local in my browser, all I see is the Drupal page saying that I have not created a first page!

I am almost sure that this is a configuration problem, but I cannot pin-point it. Can you help me?

Comment: If you could supply a screenshot of what you are seeing when you load the site locally, that could help with answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Drupal to connect to your new database. 
Also, make sure you have copied all the dot-files (.htaccess) as well. You will realize using a version control system is faster than rsync (although rsync is much faster than copying all files again and again).

Site migration instructions are nicely said in [this drupal.org article](https://www.drupal.org/node/776864). It's a lengthy one, so I'm quoting the part that you probably need to fix your site from current state.

> Make changes to the “Database settings” section of the settings.php
>   file, to ensure that they are pointing to the new database, with the
>   right user (which may be different that the one you used on the old
>   computer) and the right password. You may also have to adjust the
>   “base URL” if you are moving between a sub-domain and a domain level.
>   If you are moving the site to a new domain, or to localhost, also
>   check that "$cookie_domain" is not set to your old domain.

Comment: $cookie_domain is not set. Database users are OK (are the same). I will try again with a new copy. All files are transfered.

Comment: Something went wrong with the initial rsync. A second rsync fixed (most) of the problems.